# JInput fails when displaying all the controllers connected to my pc

Tags: java, jinput

JInput fails when displaying all the controllers connected to my pc.

I tried with System.setProperty("net.java.games.input.useDefaultPlugin", "false"); but when i put that line of code the controllers array become an empty list. I found similar posts but none helps.

Just in case, i correctly implemented libraries and i tried modifying the library path but is all correct.

This is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Controller[] controllers = ControllerEnvironment.getDefaultEnvironment().getControllers();
        
        Controller controller;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < controllers.length; i++) {
            controller = controllers[0];
            System.out.println(controller.getName());
        }
        
    }
```

And the output is like this:

```
[21:26:44] [net.java.games.input.DefaultControllerEnvironment/WARNING]: Found unknown Windows version: Windows 11
[21:26:44] [net.java.games.input.DefaultControllerEnvironment/INFO]: Attempting to use default windows plug-in.
[21:26:44] [net.java.games.input.DefaultControllerEnvironment/INFO]: Loading: net.java.games.input.DirectAndRawInputEnvironmentPlugin
[21:26:44] [net.java.games.input.ControllerEnvironment/INFO]: Failed to initialize device HIDI2C Device because of: java.io.IOException: Failed to acquire device (8007001e)

HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device
```

(By the way, i don't have 600 keyboard conected)
I have connected this devices:

- Touchpad
- Laptop integrated keyboard
- External keyboard
- Mouse